# asp:new listview javascript question

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview

I have a .net 4 asp.net website.  There is a listview with a checkbox in each "cell" of the listview.  I'd like to attach some javascript to these checkboxes in that when the check box is checked/unchecked, it changes the color of teh asp:tablecell.  The listview is bound to a collection.

I don't want to do a postback on each check change as there may be quite a few checkboxes changed.

Am i taking the wrong approach or would javascript be a good approach and if so, can someone help with the javascript.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this in the ItemDataBound event of the ListView.  Say you have the following javascript function:

```
function changeClass(checkBoxId, containerId) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById(checkBoxId);
    var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
    if(checkBox.checked == true) container.style.backgroundColor = "#AAA";
    else  container.style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";
}
```

Then, you can use FindControl in ItemDataBound like so:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = e.Item.FindControl("nameOfCheckBox");
    var container = e.Item.FindControl("nameOfTableCell");

    checkBox.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:changeClass('"
        + checkBox.ClientID + "','"
        + container.ClientID + "');";
}
```

Comment: thanks for that... i'm still having a problem in giving the asp:tablecell an ID.  I've tried something like this ID='<%# databinder.eval(container.dataitem,"ID")%>'.

Comment: Do you have to give the tablecell such a specific ID?  My solution was designed for situations where the tablecell has an ID of, say, "TableCell1".

Comment: Thanks for the help.. i figured out what i was doing wrong.  I need to make the check box just be 2 states, but this got me going.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you can attach the javascript events to the controls to attributes..property

like below//

```
seversidecontrolID.Attributes.Add("onclick","Javascript:
methodName(this);")
```